# Netatalk on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I try to install Netatalk 3.1.10 on Ubuntu 16.04 to set up a time machine backup on my server.

I try to follow this instruction:
http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Install_Netatalk_3.1.10_on_Ubuntu_16.10_Yakkety

I installed all the required packages.
But I have no idea where I have to install the Netatalk files that I downloaded.

Is there a better instruction that you know about? (I'm kind of new to the whole Linux topic.)

Comment: Netatalk is already in the repositories, just do `sudo apt install netatalk`

Comment: it is, but it is 2.x not the new one 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions you found are good. You should just know basics of the generic *“configure, make, make install”* process. You may read e.g. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install or try to google the terms yourself.

> But I have no idea where i have to install the Netatalk files that I downloaded.

You can *build* them anywhere you want, a subfolder of your home folder is a good choice. Then the command `sudo make install` copies the results into the right place.

Comment: @flaschenzug If I helped to solve your problem, please mark my answer [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer). It is worth more than saying thanks on this site. :-)

Comment: oh, I didn't know that I can to that. Just voted up. But Know i accepted. Thanks :)

And the installation worked... (with your help). Know I have some problems with the "/usr/local/etc/afp.conf".